# JSX spread operator usage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

In a tutorial I came across the following code:

```
import React from 'react';

const withClass = (WrappedComponent, className) => {
    return (props) => (
        <div className={className}>
            <WrappedComponent {...props}/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default withClass;
```

Now I know what the code does but I can't figure out how using the spread operator `{...props}` on a JSX element causes all the elements to be on the `<WrappedComponent />`. I also know that JSX is compiled to `React.createElement()`function calls and is basically all JS.

How would this spread operator syntax `{...props}` look if it was translated into `React.createElement` calls (i.e. what would be the compiled JS)?

Comment: [`Object.assign({}, props)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) should behave the same.

Comment: `createElement(WrappedComponent, props)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would this spread operator syntax {...props} look if it was translated into react.createElement calls?

Since you don't clarify *which* props are passed down, I am going to assume the props `foo`, `bar` and `baz`. Of course, this could be any number of props:

```
React.createElement(
  WrappedComponent,
  {foo: props.foo, bar: props.bar, baz: props.baz}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The spread operator will pass all object's keys to your component. Therefore, React will transform your code in this way:

```
React.createElement(WrappedComponent, props);
```

Answer (score 0):

The babel will compile your code to accept `props` as the argument to element which Javascript is going to create.

So your code will compile like this

```
var withClass = function withClass(WrappedComponent, className) {
    return function (props) {
        return React.createElement(
            "div",
            { className: className },
            React.createElement(WrappedComponent, props)
        );
    };
};
```

as If you send an object without using spread operatior it will be similar to this example

```
  <WrappedComponent allProps={"hello"}/>
```

to

```
  React.createElement(WrappedComponent, { allProps: "hello" })
```

You can try out how babel compiles the code in plain Javascript with the help of tool [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBA7gSygCwMIBsCGEIwLwwAUA6gE6YAOFApgCaogC2F41YUANDMFjgHKZG1AJT4AfDADeAKBhyYpalACupMEQqkQFCKLwTCs-cYA8tBADduvCAKF5JPbLcHUAvmKPHvME2Uo09EwsYGywmOjoAApaOg4ARMjUkSDxbgD0nj5yJunmFlnywgDc0m5AA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)